# A markov chain is regular and recurrent

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, proof-explanation

> If a Markov chain is irreducible, with finite states and aperiodic, then the Markov chain is regular and recurrent.

Proof: (part of it)

Since the Markov chain is irreducible, it is possible to get from state $i$ to state $j$, so $p_{ij}^{(k)} > 0$ for some $k$.  Then $p_{ij}^{(n+k)} \ge p_{ii}^{(n)} p_{ij}^{(k)}$, so $$\sum_{n\ge 0} p_{ij}^{(n)} \ge \sum_{n\ge k} p_{ij}^{(n)} = \sum_{n\ge 0} p_{ij}^{(n+k)}\ge p_{ij}^{(k)} \sum_{n \ge 0} p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty$$

Therefore the MC is recurrent (Because of proposition: A MC is recurrent iff $\sum_n p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty$).

Why this equality  $p_{ij}^{(k)}\sum_{n \ge 0} p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty$ holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With probability $1$ the number of returns to the recurrent state $i$ given that we start at $i$ is infinite. We can view the sum you've mentioned $\sum_{n\geq 0}{p_{ii}^{(n)}}$ as being the expected number of returns to state $i$ (this may take some convincing). It becomes clear if we define the random variable $N:= |\{n \geq 0 : x_n = i\}|$ (with $|\cdot|$ being the cardinality), and then recognize 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N|_{x_0=i}] = \sum_{n\geq 0}p_{ii}^{(n)}.
\end{align*}
Since the probability of an infinite number of returns is $1$, it must be that this expected value is infinite.

For reference, you can look at some course notes by Roman Vershynin at [this link to a .pdf](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~romanv/teaching/2017-18/525/04-11.pdf). The notes seem to closely follow the Ross textbook on probability.